# replace string value and boundry spaces if they exist

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have a string and am trying to findout what's a better way by
replacing (the boundry spaces as well if they exist)

while also replacing the value without 
doing multipule passes (ie calling, `trim_multispace` and `trimed_result`).

```
var replaceVal = "c";
var strVals = "a b c d e f g h";

var replacedVal = strVals.replace(new RegExp("\\b"+replaceVal+"\\b",""),"");

alert(replacedVal)

var trim_multispace = replacedVal.replace(/ +(?= )/g,'');
var trimed_result = trim_multispace.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');

alert(trimed_result)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if I got you correctly, but this regex works in the way you specified

```
strVals.replace(new RegExp(replaceVal, 'g'), '')
       .replace(/ +/g, ' ').replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
```

Comment: Thanks! Narendra, and why did you edit your answer the original worked fine?

Comment: @david I added a `g` flag to `RegExp` constructor to do a global replace of `replaceVal`. That is if `replaceVal` is found anywhere in the string multiple times all occurrences will be replaced. I thought that would suit your scenario.

Comment: just to let you know the newly append global flag causes your solution to fail for my case, because it will replace any occurrences for `replaceVal` like `a b c d e f g hc` `c` will be removed from `hc`

Comment: @david do you need to replace multiple occurrences of 'c' if occurred in isolation? for example do you want `a b c d c e c` to be reduced to `a b d e`. if so let me know, i will modify the regex according by adding boundary conditions to the above regex. it would look like this `new RegExp('\\b'+replaceVal+'\\b', 'g')`. if you want only the first occurrence of `replaceVal` to be replaced then you use this  `new RegExp('\\b'+replaceVal+'\\b', '')`. let me know in either case, i will update the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The following does this in almost one step, first replace the value and any surrounding whitespace with a single space, then trim the result:

```
var replacedVal = strVals.replace(new RegExp("\\s*"+replaceVal+"\\s*", ""), " ").trim();
```

Comment: This would not reduce multiple spaces anywhere in the string into a single space. Another thing is `trim` function is available only from Javascript 1.8.1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim

Comment: According to the question, that isn't a requirement.  OP only mentions boundary spaces around the value that is being replaced, although the original code would have the side effect of removing all multiple spaces as well.